# Confidence interval for a set of means with no standard errors

Tags: anova, confidence-interval

Is it possible to construct a confidence interval for a set of means, from samples with equal numbers of observations, if the standard errors of those samples are unknown?

Comment: You construct a CI for an unknown (population) quantity, not a set of observations (including observed means). Can you clarify whether you want a CI or some other kind of interval (such as a tolerance interval say), and if you want a CI, what it's intended to be an interval for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume that the standard deviations of the underlying populations the samples are drawn from are the same* then you could compute a CI for an underlying common mean.

* (as they would be if they were in reality a single population that it would make sense to compute a CI for the mean of).

That is, if you have $g$ samples each of size $n$, from which you observe $y_i = \bar{x}_i, i=1,2,...,g$, then the standard deviation of the $y$'s is a sensible estimate of $\sigma_\bar{X} = \sigma_x/\sqrt{n}$.

In particular if $X_{ij}\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then you can directly construct a CI for $\mu$ from the $\bar{x}_i$ values; if you don't assume normality for the common distribution of the $X$'s but the $n$'s are "large enough" then you can still construct an approximate CI for $\mu$ based off the $t$-distribution - even if $g$ is small - because the distribution of the $\bar{X}$'s should be close to normal.

On the other hand, if $n$ is small but $g$ is large then you can use a different argument to construct an asymptotically normal CI for $\mu$.

Comment: Great answer, this is exactly what I needed to know, thank you. 

Yes, I am assuming the underlying population is the same. I would like to make two clarifications if you don't mind: Following your equation, when estimating the standard deviation of all means, is **_n_** the total number of observations in all samples or is it the number of observations in each individual sample? And, in the numerator, this is the single standard deviation derived from all of the means together, correct?

Comment: The opening sentence of my third paragraph answers your first question ("if you have $g$ samples *each of size* $n$"). Yes, by "standard deviations of the $y$'s" I mean "consider the means like a sample and compute a standard deviation from them*, to act directly as an estimate $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ for the original data.